# Como passar valores de uma activity para outra

Tags: java, android, xml, smartdevice

eu vim aqui para saber como que eu faço para passar dados de uma Activity para outra, já tentei isso:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, other.class)
i.putExtra("NAME", name);
```

Mas quando tento pegar da outra Acticity e compilo o programa da erro e ele para de funcionar. Oque eu faço agora????

Comment: Qual o erro que retorna?

Comment: A aplicaçao simplesmente para, sem dqr

Comment: Coloca aqui o que aparece no logcat para sabermos o erro. 
Exemplo aqui:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android